# Understanding of the verse

Tags: quran, hadith, ramadan

As Salamuwalikum rahmatullahi barakatuh. I have question regarding Quran 886:5-7. I have seen many argument for and against this verse.

Here is couple explanation

1: semen is produced in seminal vesical and prostate gland. Both of which are in between backbone and ribs. (Between backbone and ribs is thoracic region (i.e heart, lungs etc.) how is this between backbones and ribs.

2. It's referring to human not fluid as ibn atiyyah and Iman qurtubi mentions in their tafsir. But again the question is; baby is located in abdominal region not backbone and ribs (thoracic region).

What am I missing here? Please someone help me. Jazakallah Khair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The verses are

> فَلْيَنظُرِ ٱلْإِنسَـٰنُ مِمَّ خُلِقَ
>
> (So let man reflect on what he was created from -)
>
> خُلِقَ مِن مَّآءٍۢ دَافِقٍۢ
>
> (A spurting fluid)
>
> يَخْرُجُ مِنۢ بَيْنِ ٱلصُّلْبِ وَٱلتَّرَآئِبِ
>
> (That comes from between the backbone and the ribs.)

The testes that produce the sperm that fertilise the ova, and the ovaries that produce the ova, are formed in the abdomen of the foetus, later developing to acquire their position in the pelvis. Therefore, the verse either refers to the origin (in the developmental sense), or in the sense that they are sustained by arteries located between the backbone and the ribs.

Comment: Jazakallah Khair for the answer. I seen this explanation. But my question is when Allah says "emerge from between backbone and ribs" is it referring to just thoracic region, as in where the ribcage ends. Or Allah says from rib to coccyx. If that makes sense